# ms outlook 2013 addressentry ID is not unique

Tags: vba, outlook

Everything I read about MS Outlook says the addressentry.id is unique.  but mine don't appear to be.

Here's some code:

```
Dim anaddressentry As AddressEntry
Dim listuniqueid As String
Dim lastlistunique As String
Dim kount As Integer
lastlistunique = "none"
For kount = 1 To 20
    For Each anaddressentry In Session.AddressLists.Item(2).AddressEntries
        If anaddressentry.Name = "testcontactgroup" Then
            listuniqueid = anaddressentry.ID
            If lastlistunique <> "none" Then
                If lastlistunique <> listuniqueid Then
                    Stop
                End If
            End If
            lastlistunique = listuniqueid
        End If
    Next
Next
```

It runs the same routine 20 times where it goes through my contacts and looks for something with the name "testcontactgroup"  then it gets it's addressentry.id.  If this isn't the first time, it compares it with the last addressentry.id it got for that contact.

If they aren't the same, it stops.  As I understand it, they should always be the same.

They're close to the same, except for the last few characters.

here are two values I get for the id for the same address entry

00000000FE42AA0A18C71A10E8850B651C2400000300000005000000FF000000180000000000000058D0304A0573A945BD70D6FBA5D114FAC416A000000090

00000000FE42AA0A18C71A10E8850B651C2400000300000005000000FF000000180000000000000058D0304A0573A945BD70D6FBA5D114FAC416A00060209B

Any suggestions?

thanks

bob

Answer (score 1):

That entry id refers to a contact in one of your Contacts folders. It includes (besides a few flags) the email kind (email1, email2, fax, etc.). and the entry id of the corresponding IPM.Contact message (ContactItem object).

You should never directly compare entry ids - that is what Namespace.CompareEntryIDs is for: multiple entry ids can refer to the same object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is there any field (or part of a field) that's unique and really doesn't change about contacts and groups?  I have an Access database with clients and I want to be able to save some identifier of a list and/or contacts to whom we mail things for them.  So I was planning to save these unique identifiers in an access table and when the time comes to mail stuff the program would look up the identifier in the contacts and send the email.